# Optimal MySQL table schema for given use case

Tags: mysql, redis, query-optimization, primary-key, database-indexes

I have two tables - `books` and `images`. The `books` table has many columns - including `id` (primary key), `name` (which is not unique), `releasedate`, etc. The `images` table have two columns - `id` (which is not unique, i.e one book id may have multiple images associated with it, and we need all those images. This column has a non-unique index), and `poster` (which is unique primary key, all images lie in the same bucket, hence cannot have duplicate names). My requirement is given a book name, find all images associated with it (along with the year of release and the `bucketname` for each image, the `bucketname` being just a number in this case).

I am running this query:

```
select books.id,poster,bucketname,year(releasedate) from books 
inner join images where images.bookId = books.id and books.name = "<name>";
```

A sample result set may look like this:

[image]

As you can see there are two results matching - one with `id` 2 and `year` 1989, having 5 images, other one with `id` 261009, `year` 2013 and one image.

The problem is, the query is extremely slow. It takes around .14 seconds from MySQL console itself, under zero load (in production there may be several concurrent requests and they may be queued, leading to further delay), which is unacceptable for autocomplete. Can anyone tell me how to optimize the query by adding correct indices/keys to the tables? If it is not possible from MySQL, suggestions regarding a proper Redis schema would be useful as well.

Edit: Approx no. of rows in `images` - 480k, in `books` - 285k. In future, autocomplete will show result for book authors as well as book names, hence the query will need to expand to take into account a separate table `authors` where each author will have an `id` and `name`, just like a book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For optimal performance, you want suitable covering indexes available. For example:

```
... on `books` (`name`,`id`,`releasedate`)
... on `images` (`bookid`,`poster`,`bucketname`)
```

We want `name` as the leading column in the index, because of the equality predicate in the WHERE clause. We want id and releasedate also included in the index to make it a "covering index", so the query can be satisfied from the index, without a need to visit pages of the underlying table to retrieve values.

We want `bookid` as the leading column because of the reference in the ON clause. Again, having `poster` and `bucketname` available right in the index make it a "covering" index.
Use `EXPLAIN` to see the query execution plan.

Also, note that the inner join operation won't return a row from `books` if a matching row in `images` is not found. If we want to return a row from `books` even when no image is available, we could use an outer join.

I'd write the query like this:

```
SELECT b.id
     , i.poster
     , i.bucketname
     , YEAR(b.releasedate)
  FROM books b
  LEFT
  JOIN images i
    ON i.bookid = b.id
 WHERE b.name = ?
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you give the complete syntax for the covering index with respect to my table example? And this on top of the existing keys and indices, or do I drop them?

Comment: e.g. **`CREATE INDEX \`book_IX4\``** `on \`books\` (\`name\`,\`id\`,\`releasedate\`)`.  This can be added along with existing indexes.  This new index would make an index on just the `name` column redundant, unless the existing index is being used to enforce uniqueness.  That is, any query that can make use of the index on just `name` can make use of the index on the three columns, because `name` is the leading column.

Comment: Lord almighty, that took it to .00087 seconds! Thanks buddy! Just one question, I am adding a covering key including `poster` in the `images` table, whereas `poster` itself is already a primary key. Will this cause any problems, like taking up lots of space, or making inserts slower?

Comment: Yes, the index will use additional space (blocks) on disk, and in the innodb buffer pool (assuming the table is using innodb storage engine);  and yes, the index entries will need to be maintained for DML (insert/update/delete) operations on the table. Indexes aren't "free", so we definitely don't want to create and maintain redundant indexes, or indexes that won't be of any benefit. And these kind of concerns are why we typically like our indexes, especially the primary key, to be on *short* columns... integers, datetime, short character columns, not on huge character columns.

Comment: But in this case, we will needs the `poster` to be a primary key because there will be queries to search just a poster. Sigh...

Comment: Given that `poster` is the primary key of the `images` table, that's going to be included in every secondary index (as a pointer to the row in the table). So including it in a secondary index... `(bookid,poster)` shouldn't cost anything more than a secondary index on that doesn't include that column... `(bookid)`.

Comment: Ah, makes sense.. This is because non-clustered index always uses clustered index in the background to do the search, right?

Comment: Right.  The secondary index has a pointer to the row in the table, and for InnoDB, that's the cluster key. And if you have a primary key defined on the table, that'll be the cluster key. The trick with a "covering index" for a query is that MySQL doesn't have to follow the pointer back to the table to find the block in the table pages. The query can be satisfied entirely from the index blocks. Where MySQL makes use of a covering index, the EXPLAIN output will show "Using index" in the Extra column.

Comment: ` .00087 seconds` smells like the "Query cache" kicked in.  Double check by timing `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...`.